# Add mirror drive to existing (unmirrored) Storage Space without losing data?

Tags: windows, storage-spaces

Given an existing simple (non-resilient) Storage Space pool (2x2Tb drives), could I non-destructively add a third (4Tb) drive to the pool as a mirror of the two existing drives?